# Paho JS can't connect to Mosquitto Server

Tags: message-queue, mqtt, messagebroker, mosquitto, paho

When I try to connect to Mosquitto server through this JS, I receive this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I tried from console and it works fine.
I tried with Java client as provider and consumer and it works fine.
So I can't undertand what should I do to have it working.

This is JS:

```
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 1883, "clientId");

client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

// connect the client
client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});
```

This is Java (working):

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PahoManager implements MqttCallback {

  MqttClient client;

  public void init() {
      try {
          client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.50.10:1883", "pahomqttpublish1");

          client.connect();
          client.subscribe("pahodemo/test");
      } catch (MqttException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }    

  public void doDemo()  {
    try {

      MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
      message.setPayload("Ciao Pluto".getBytes());
      client.publish("pahodemo/test", message);

      //client.disconnect();
    } catch (MqttException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable thrwbl) {
        System.out.println("Connection Lost");
    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String string, MqttMessage mm) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Message: " + string + mm);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken imdt) {
        System.out.println("Message delivered");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you got websockets server running? mosquitto at the moment doesn't have built in support for websockets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As hardillb said, mosquitto **does not** yet support websockets. If you want native websockets, there are other solutions like [HiveMQ](http://www.hivemq.com). You can see a full list of brokers with websocket support [here](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/Server%20support) (you may need to scroll the table to the right). You can learn more about MQTT over websockets in [this blog post](http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-over-websockets-with-hivemq/):

Please make sure, that you are connecting to the websocket port which is usually *not* 1883. In practice this means, that your TCP MQTT clients connect to port 1883 and your websocket clients to another port like 8000.

The usual disclaimer: I'm one of the HiveMQ developers so this answer may be biased ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Mosquitto version 1.4 to get websockets support. This has not been released yet, but you can build it yourself. The source is available here:

https://bitbucket.org/oojah/mosquitto/branch/1.4

The other option is to run a websocket to MQTT bridge. You can use the lighttpd module described here:

http://test.mosquitto.org/ws.html

Comment: Mosquitto 1.4 has been released in Feb 2015, with built-in support for websockets.